# Hide border and child controls on mouse left button click outside in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, border

I have below border:

```
    <Border CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="DarkBlue" 
            BorderThickness="1"  
            Background="AntiqueWhite">
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="/Resources/Info_48.png" 
                       Height="20" 
                       Width="20" 
                       Stretch="Fill"/>
                <TextBlock Width="90" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           Background="Transparent" 
                           FontSize="12">
                     <Run Text="This is a Popup simulation"/>
                 </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

This border is being visible when a panel is shown. Once border and child components are shown, they will be automatically hidden on mouse click wherever in the window.

What I am trying to do is to detect mouse click event outside the boder and its child components. Once click detected outside, I need to hide the border and its child components similar to popup when StaysOpen=false and it is automatically hidden on mouse click.

How can I detect mouse click outside the control?

Answer (score 0):

set style for border to visible or hide the border by change the color or etc..

```
<Border  Background="Transparent" 
     Height="18" Width="18">
 <Border.Style>
    <Style Target-type="Border">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="visibility" Value="false" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to hide border and all its child components when user clicks wherever outside the control. For example, create an popup control and set StaysOpen to false, then click wherever outside the popup control and see what happens: when you click outside popup is hidden, I want the same behavior. In your example, it is hidden on mouse over.